# Xcode generating Swift Packages for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I am trying to create Swift Packages using the built-in features of XCode 11, but I am having issues. I am able to create generic Swift Package (no platforms) and Swift Package for Mac (platform .macos), but when I try to create ones for iOS only, the compiler tells me that UIKit can not be imported.  I see the message:

"UIKit is not available when building for MacOS. Consider using '#if !os(macOS)' to conditionally import this framework."

I am using XCode to generate this package, not any command line generation of a Swift Package. The package does not have an Xcode project file associated with it, it is simply a package. If I place conditional compiles around the iOS code, the project builds successfully because it skips the iOS portion. However, this way does not show me any compile errors that might be in the code!

If I do compile, and publish with the conditional macros, I can then import the Swift Package into an iOS project, and the code compiles.  However, debugging takes forever, since if I have an compile error in the package, I have to edit the Package, commit, push, update, then run it within the Mac project to see if I got it right. I would like to have the Swift Package correct compile the code, so I can fix it there.

Help?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are step by step instructions for creating a Swift package for iOS using Xcode 11.5.

1. Choose File > New > Swift Package.
2. Accept the default name MyLibrary and save to the desktop.
3. To the existing *MyLibrary.swift* file inside Sources/MyLibrary, add an import of UIKit, and just for good measure let's actually refer to a UIKit class. And let's make everything public, so that it looks like this:

   ```
   import UIKit
   public struct MyLibrary {
       public init() {}
       public var view = UIView()
   }
   ```
4. In `MyLibraryTests.swift` inside Tests/MyLibraryTests, delete the entire `final class MyLibraryTests` declaration.
5. At the top of window, where it says MyLibrary > My Mac, change My Mac to Generic iOS Device or any iOS Simulator that you may happen to have installed.
6. Build.

Now, to prove that this works, import the package into an iOS project. You will be able to `import MyLibrary` and create a `MyLibrary()` object and obtain its `view`.

---

Personally, I don't think that's a very good way to develop a package for iOS; I would rather add the package to an existing project, so that there's a test bed where I can actually run the code immediately. Still, this proves that you can create a stand-alone package and compile it for iOS.

Comment: Thank you Matt. The key point I was missing was that the Swift Package uses a the selected Device to determine what platform to compile the Swift Package again. I needed to change the "My Mac" setting to one of the iOS Simulator ones.  I agree with you that you should probably develop a library inside another project, and then move it to a Package when you want it to be available for other people and project.  However, even in that case, you want the code to compile correctly, so that the Unit Tests that are included with the package successfully run.  Steve

Comment: Your comment saved me Matt!

Comment: I'm getting `No such module 'UIKit'` when I do this.

Comment: @ScottyBlades If you have a question, please ask it as an actual question. Blip me here and I'll be glad to take a look. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you @matt, I actually figured out the issue.  I was trying to run the project but didn't realize the default simulator is for Mac.

Comment: Hi @ScottyBlades Sorry i am also getting the same error `No such module 'UIKit`. Can you give me the exact steps for solve this issue